# How to see NAT table?

Tags: router, nat

I just started reading about computer networks. Now I am on NAT on routers.
I read that the router assigns an higher port for outgoing request and translates to the correct lower port once the server replies.

Is it possible for me to see the NAT table of a router. Is it kept hidden from user or , is it possible to see which ports are assigned for outgoing request?

Comment: It's not really "higher" or whatever. It *may* simply be another ephemeral port. Ephemeral ports are already high by default on modern operating systems.

Comment: Sounds right except it's not "higher vs lower", it's merely "outside vs inside". 'Higher' might be merely a side effect of the router enforcing port randomization, which Windows only started doing itself very recently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the router, but very often it's actually shown in the web configuration page, somewhere under "Status → Connections" or such.

For Linux-based routers, if you have SSH/Telnet access, you can read the *conntrack* state table:

```
# conntrack -L                  -- has options to livestream and modify the states
# cat /proc/net/nf_conntrack    -- for current kernels (on PCs)
# cat /proc/net/ip_conntrack    -- for older kernels (on embedded routers)
```

For BSD-based routers (e.g. pfSense), the same can be done via *pf*:

```
# pfctl -ss
```